# How do I make a query run based off a selection in a ListBox in Access?

Tags: ms-access, listbox

I have a DB created with information in a few tables.

In the table I have a category in one of the columns labeled as "Supplier"

On the main form of the DB I have a listbox that has all of the suppliers that are in the table. When I click on the supplier name it generates all of the Part Numbers in a separate listbox below. I want to be able to click on the Part Number and then click a button and then it will bring up all the information in the table or all fields in the table based off of the selected part number from that listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the samples from the link below.

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut18.htm

Martin has lots of good stuff here as well!!

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/index.htm